# How to make jquery load() in external javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to create my own tool in javascript, which will help me load some php functions/files into my div.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function() {        
        $('#someid').testit();
        //   $('#someid').load('somefile');  it works
        return false;
    })   
});

function testit() { 
    $(this).load('somefile');
}
```

And my html:

```
<div id="someid"></div>
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="test" class="btn" />
</form>
```

I can't load the resource from external function - why is that?

Comment: It really does'nt work that way! you can't just create a regular function and chain it to a jQuery object, but you could use jQuery's $.fn constructor to make a chainable plugin, and it's all explained on the [**plugin authoring**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) site of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but is it a way to fire my own JS function on some Jquery selector?

Comment: And again, it does'nt work that way? You could pass the element as a paremeter in the function, like : `testit(filename, element)`, but you can't chain the function to the element.

Comment: Here's a really quick example : [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hreq/1/)

Comment: Thanky you ; ) I'll try to do it that way - it's WAY more elegant : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call something like:

```
$('#someid').testit();
```

Then, you have to create a jQuery plugin that defines the method `testit`.  That code would look something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.testit = function() {
    return this.load('somefile');
}
```

Then, and only then can you use `testit()` as a jQuery method like this:

```
$('#someid').testit();
```

And, it will operate on the desired selector.

Here's some of the [jQuery doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) on writing plugin methods like this.

Comment: I simplified the plugin function a bit since `.load()` already iterates the jQuery object for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like below:

```
$.fn.testit = function () {
  return this.load('somefile');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't chain functions like that out of the box, you'd have to put it into the jquery.fn prototype to make a plugin.

What you could do instead is use the `.each()` function on the selector to call your function.

In your case, if you were to call `$("#someid").each(testit);` jquery will then call the testit() function on each of the elements found.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function() {        
        testit($('#someid'));
        return false;
    })   
});

function testit(el) { 
    el.load('somefile');
}
```

Or create a JQuery plugin as jfriend00 mentions